# quickest way to try/install redmine?

Tags: installation, operating-systems, redmine

I want to try the trunk version of Redmine to find out if it suits my needs

Could somebody help me/point me what OS (win or linux+what distro) is the best to use in terms of **easy and quick install of Redmine** and all of its components and required pieces of sw?

Or is there any all in one package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order of easiness/ speed:

1. Try the [online demo](http://demo.redmine.org/).
2. [Download](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/redmine) [One](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine) of the available virtual machines with it installed.
3. Follow the instructions [here](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/RedmineInstall)

Comment: I already tried online demo but was told to use trunk code to explore the latest features. Bitnami looks very good. Thank you for that!!!

Comment: it seems to me that turnkey linux is the ONE

Comment: any idea what I need to download to try redmine. turnkey package (but which one) and VirtualBox?

Comment: Download and install [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).


Download the Turnkey virtual machine. Extract the files from the zip file. In Virtualbox do File->Import and select the turnkey-stuff.OVF file. Start the new virtual machine.


Once the network has been set up (I used bridged mode in the virtual machine setting - the virtua lmachine then gets added to my LAN with an IP address from my router.) you can then enter the virtual machine's IP address in your web browser address bar.

Comment: Hmmm.... nice idea :)

Answer (score 5):

Redmine install procedure on Redmine wiki is not very clear for beginners like me :)

On Windows, I recommend installing it through [MS Web Platform Installer and Helicon Zoo gallery](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/installing-redmine-on-windows-in-production/) (follow procedures on given link).

It will download and install all required software in a few clicks.

[image: a windowshot of what i'm talking about]